# ASP.NET Core on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, nginx

I have problem with ASP.NET Core on Linux. I have VPS server, on this I've got my application which was good on local. Problem is in file uploads.
I dont have idea why I have 
[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjVSa.png)

My code for this works for me on the local host, and local directory.

```
public static async Task<List<FileDetail>> UploadFileAsync(this IHostingEnvironment _host,
        ApplicationDbContext _context, 
        int Id, 
        IFormFileCollection files)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<files.Count; i++)
        {
            var file = files[i];
            if(file != null && file.Length > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    FileDetail fileDetail = new FileDetail()
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        FileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName),
                        Extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower(),
                        TicketId = Id,
                    };
                    var uploads = Path.Combine(_host.WebRootPath, "Uploads");
                    const string back = "/";
                    const string slash = @"\";
                    var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, fileDetail.Id + fileDetail.Extension);
                    filePath = filePath.Replace(slash,back);
                    fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create); //there is a problem
                    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    fileDetails.Add(fileDetail);
                    _context.FileDetail.Add(fileDetail);
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    fileStream.Close(); //this is my 48 line.
                }
            }
        }
        return fileDetails;
    }
```

I think it's problem with permission to folder, but I don't have experience in Linux and nginx service. Can someone help me, and solve this problem ?

Comment: youve got an object is not an instance of an object error so something is not being initialised, are you able to point out which line of you code is line 143 in the Ticket Controller

Comment: In Ticket Controller line 143 is:
fileDetails = await FileUploadAsync(...);

Comment: Why you did this ? filePath.Replace(slash,back); if you use Path.Combine than I don't think it is required. it will automatically choose  right one. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I thought that is going on wrong path, that's the reason :/

Comment: ok, try changing `Path.Combine(_host.WebRootPath, "Uploads")` to `"~/Uploads"` or `"~/someotherfolder/uploads"` depending on your folder structure.

Comment: Also, on your local machine and the host machine the WebRootPath could be something totally different so you need to understand what this is on your host machine

Comment: @SimonPrice Not working :/ I changed this Path but still :/

Comment: whats the actual value of upload when youre calling it in your host environment